# Recurrence relation and induction

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

I have this given recurrence relation:

$T(n) = 3T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$

Initial value: $T(1) = 1$

and I should show that $T(n) = O(n^{\alpha})$ and $\alpha = log_2(3)$

to solve that I should define: $P(n) :\Leftrightarrow T(n) \leq n^{\alpha}$ and $P(n)$ holds for all $n \geq 1$ and I should show that by induction.

But I don't understand what that $P(n) :\Leftrightarrow T(n) \leq n^{\alpha}$ means?

Is $P(n) = T(n)$?

---

solution:

**Base:**

$n \geq 1$ and $n = 1$

$$3T(\lfloor 1/2 \rfloor) \leq 1^{log_2(3)}$$

$$\lfloor 3/2 \rfloor \leq 1^{log_2(3)}$$

$$1 \leq 1$$

**Hypothesis:**

$$3T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) \leq n^{log_2(3)}$$

**Step:**

$T(n) = 3T(\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor) \\ 
\leq (\frac{n}{2})^{log_2(3)} \\
= 3^{log_2(\frac{n}{2})} \\
= 3^{log_2(n)- log_2(2)} \\
= 3^{log_2(n)- 1} \\
\leq 3^{log_2(n)} = n^{log_2(3)}
$

is that right?

Comment: $P(n)$ is not a function but $T(n)$ is, $P(n)$ is a proposition.

Comment: ok but how should I define P(n)? Is it not possible to do the induction on T(n)?

Comment: I don't think it is the best way to prove it, moreover $T(n)=\mathcal{O}(n^{\alpha})$ doesn't mean that $T(n)\leqslant n^{\alpha}$, it means that there exists $C>0$ such that $T(n)\leqslant C n^{\alpha}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I would suggest to study $u_p=T(2^p)$ that verifies $u_{p+1}=3u_p$, show by induction that $T$ is increasing, then use $T(n)\leqslant u_{1+\lfloor \log_2(n)\rfloor}$.

Comment: ok thanks I think now I get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove, by induction on the number of binary digits of $n$, that $T(n)=3^{\lfloor\log_2n\rfloor}$. Since $3^{\log_2n}=n^{\log_23}$, $\frac13n^{\log_23}\lt T(n)\le n^{\log_23}$.

Comment: why ist T(n) =3 ^⌊log2n⌋?

Comment: @ArminZierlinger For $j\in\{0,\,1\}$, $T(2n+j)=3T(n)$. Apart from the factor of $3$, we've deleted the last binary digit of $T$'s argument. Now repeat. The first such digit is $1$.

Comment: is that now right?

Comment: @ArminZierlinger No.